# How to do uncensored cox regression in R?

Tags: r, survival

First of all, I'm not sure if the analysis name is uncensored cox or it has other names.

I watched [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3Hil0I9eyw&t=150s), which is done in stata. So, anyone can recommend any package in R that able to do this? Or any links how to do this?

Comment: The [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) has a [`coxph` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/coxph.html) and a [related vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/tests.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Just make sure the all status equal to 1 and run normal cox in survival package.

I just put the answer here, in case anyone run into the same question.